# Probar aplicacion en real en iphone.¿Dónde está la base datos sqlite?

Tags: base-de-datos, sqlite

Estoy empezando en la programación Swift.  Os resumo. Tengo una aplicación en swift, la pruebo con los emuladores de iphone 11 en xcode. Dicha aplicación tiene una base de datos en sqlite. Cuando realizo las consultas en el simulador funciona bien. El problema es.. CUANDO QUIERO PROBAR DICHA APLICACION EN UN IPHONE REAL, porque NO ENCUENTRO la ruta donde almacena la base de datos, es decir, para encontrar la base de datos hago

let dbfile = bundle.main.url(forResource: "Basedatos.sqlite",withExtension:nil!)

if let filecontents = try? String(contentsOf:dbFile)

...

if sqlite3_open(dbfile.paht. &BaseDatos) ! = SQLITE_OK

....

Bien, así consigo en local la ruta donde está almacenada la base de datos, y no hay problema.
El problema es cuando lo pruebo en un iphone real.. porque.. NO ENCUENTRA LA RUTA donde se almacena la base de datos.
Llevo probando cosas casi 1 mes y no encuentro solución, por favor, ayuda.

¡¡ Gracias !!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! siempre que digas que llevas probando cosas, agrega todas las cosas que probaste, asi podemos ver en que te equivocaste en cada cosa que probaste...

Comment: `forResource` es en el Bundle del projecto, es solo para leer.